# How to make checkboxes readonly using multipledropdown.js in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdownbox

I need to readonly all checkboxes using Angular.js `multipledropdown.js`. My code is below:

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-show="sub_sub_menu">
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Sub Sub Menu:</span>
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example17data" selected-model="example17model" checkboxes="true" extra-settings="example17settings" class="form-control oditek-form" disabled=true></div>
    </div>
</div>

var url3='../service/admin/user/group.php';
        var method3='POST';
        var data3=$.param({'action':'getAllSubSubMenuData','sub_id':$scope.smenu.value,'id':$scope.mmenu.value});
        $scope.example17data=[];
        DataService.connectToServerSideScript(method3,url3,data3)
        .then(function(response) {
            //console.log('state',response);
            if (response.length >0) {
                angular.forEach(response,function(obj){
                    var cdata={'label':obj.menu,'id':obj.id};
                    $scope.example17data.push(cdata);
                })
                angular.forEach(response,function(obj){
                    var data1={'id':parseInt(obj.id)};
                    $scope.example17model.push(data1);
                })
                $scope.sub_menu=true;
                $scope.sub_sub_menu=true;
            }else{
                $scope.sub_menu=true;
                $scope.sub_sub_menu=false;
            }
        },function(error) {

        })
```

Here I am using multiple dropdown checkbox list and all check boxes are checked by default. Here I need to readonly all checkboxes so that it can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

To make them read only you will have to disable the options. To disable them you need to add disabled property to your object. Try the following please

```
var cdata={'label':obj.menu,'id':obj.id,disabled: true};
```

Comment: @satya If you can provide a plunker, I can further help you with your problem.

Comment: I am using DB data for list so it will little bit difficult to configure.

Comment: @satya You can populate your select with dummy data.